# Conditional Formatting all cells in multiple columns based of the value of the cells in another column

Tags: excel, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I’m am trying to use conditional formatting to see which of my clients (over 100 rows) are not utilising their monthly budgets.

I have their monthly budget in H and their spend for each of the last 3 months in D, E and F.

What formula can I use that will highlight which months(cells) they didn’t utilise their budget in “red” and which months that they did in “green”.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi! Ignore the spam below. It will soon be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to take:

- Select the range of cells that have the monthly expenses.

  Assuming the data starts at row 2, this range could be E2:G999
- Once selected, choose:

  Conditional Formatting >  New Rule > Use a Formula to determine which cells to format.
- In the field "Format values where this formula is true", enter:

  ```
  =E2>=$H2
  ```
- Click the Format button to select a green background, and confirm.

Repeat the same steps to create another rule for the formatting in *red*, but now the formula is:

```
=E2<$H2
```

...and obviously the color to format with would be red.

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you. How would I adjust the formula so that months where the clients have exceeded their budgets appear in green, as currently those cells also appear in red.